# Jmeter Groovy reports NoSuchMethodError: ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant when using MSAL4J

Tags: groovy, jmeter, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to recreate a user authentication with username and password with [Microsoft Authentication Library for Java](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java) because we need to grant admin consent to a new application in a lot of tenants.

To do this, I have added a [JSR233 sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) with Groovy 2.4.16 so I can create a script to use msal4j. The script looks like this:

```
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.*;
import com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.*;
//import java.util.concurrent.*;

Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(Arrays.asList("openid","profile","email", "offline_access"));
String username = vars.get("USER");
String password = vars.get("PASSWORD");

//log.info("USER: " + username);
//log.info("PASSWORD: " + password);
log.info("SCOPE: " + scope);
log.info("CLIENT: " + vars.get("CLIENT"));

UserNamePasswordParameters parameters =
     UserNamePasswordParameters
        .builder(scope, username, password.toCharArray())
        .build();

PublicClientApplication pca = 
    PublicClientApplication.builder(vars.get("CLIENT"))
        .authority("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + vars.get("TENANT"))
        .build();             

IAuthenticationResult result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
```

When testing the sampler, however, I recieve the following error:

```
ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Thread Group 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/auth/Secret;)V
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.UserNamePasswordRequest.createAuthenticationGrant(UserNamePasswordRequest.java:22) ~[msal4j-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.UserNamePasswordRequest.<init>(UserNamePasswordRequest.java:14) ~[msal4j-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.PublicClientApplication.acquireToken(PublicClientApplication.java:35) ~[msal4j-1.8.0.jar:1.8.0]
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IPublicClientApplication$acquireToken.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:128) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at Script29.run(Script29.groovy:24) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:321) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_271]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:223) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:71) ~[ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.2.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:627) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:551) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:490) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_271]
```

I think the problem may lay in the definition of scope: `Set<String> scope = Collections.singleton(Arrays.asList("openid","profile","email", "offline_access"));` but I am not completely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into the [JavaDoc](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk/latest/com/nimbusds/oauth2/sdk/ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant.html) for the class where you getting the error I can see that it takes 2 strings as the parameters:

```
ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant​(String username, Secret password)    
Creates a new resource owner password credentials grant.
```

so most probably you're suffering from a form of a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell) so double check your dependency libraries versions as if there will be mismatch it will result into API conflicts and errors like you're facing.

Also be aware that [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-5.3) (or whatever is the latest version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page) on next available opportunity